# Computing degree of map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose two manifolds $X$ and $Y$, both orientable of dimension $n$, and a map $f:X\to Y$.

Is there a relationship between the degree of $f$ calculated with respect to homology (the induced map on the top homology groups) and the degree of $f$ calculated with respect to cohomology (the induced map on the top cohomology groups)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Yes, they are equal. I'm sure this follows from the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: I assume this requires integral (co)homology, otherwise you only get a $G$-valued degree.  But then what happens with non-orientable manifolds, e.g. $S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^2$?